# Why does this Kotlin parameter type with an upper bound need a cast?

Tags: generics, kotlin

The following function takes a list of `Serializable` and a lambda which serializes the individual elements of the list.

```
    val os = BufferOutputStream()
    fun <T : Serializable> writeList(list: List<Serializable>, emitter: (T, BufferOutputStream) -> Unit) {
        os.writeInt(list.size)
        for (v in list) {        // v is of type Serializable
            emitter(v as T, os)  // why do we need to cast V as T? 
        }
    }
```

Why would I need to cast `v` which is of type `Serializable` to `T` when `T` already has to implement `Serializable`? Doesn't `<T : Serializable>` establish that a function/lambda that takes `Serializable` must take `T`?

Comment: "Doesn't `<T : Serializable>` establish that a function/lambda that takes `Serializable` must take `T`?" It does. But you are trying to go the other way around: pass a `Serializable` to a function which takes `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet your emitter doesn't take any `Serializable` - it takes only `T`. That is the reason why you need casting - elements of the list are of type `Serializable`. If you changed it to :

```
val os = BufferOutputStream()
    fun <T : Serializable> writeList(list: List<T>, emitter: (T, BufferOutputStream) -> Unit) {
        os.writeInt(list.size)
        for (v in list) {
            emitter(v, os)
        }
    }
```

It wouldn't need casting.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post an example of why it shouldn't compile without a cast.

Imagine there are two classes `Class1` and `Class2` which implement or extend `Serializable`. If you call this function with a list that contains `Class1` but the emitter takes `Class2`, then it would be a class cast exception when taking `Class1` out of the list and passing it into the emitter which only takes `Class2`.

In the example that @r2rek posted, the function forces the list and the emitter to be the same classes.